# express API extract data from URL

Tags: javascript, express, http

My api recives every 45 minutes a request:

```
GET http://MyHost/mediciones/sigfox_libelium/{device}/{data}/{time}/{customData#trama}
```

I want my code to save {device}, {data}, {time} and {customData#trama} into different variables so I can parse it into readable values(all data it is send hexadecimal) and insert them into my database.
How do I take those values out of the URL?

Also, what is the purpose of **req, res**? I guess It stands for **request, respond**.Respond sends back to the client but, request? I dont really understand how it works. Im learning all this new, hope someone can help.

This is my API code, I tried it with postman and it works fine so far:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const pool = new Pool({
    user: "mgr@stanpgtest",
    host: "stanpgtest.postgres.database.azure.com",
    database: "my db name",
    password: "my pass",
    port: 5432
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running, listening to port 8000`);
});

app.post("mediciones/sigfox_libelium/{device}/{data}/{time}/{customData#trama}", (req, res) => {
    const { label, status, priority } = req.body;
    pool.query(
        "select now()",
        (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
              throw error;
            }
            res.send(results);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: in [Express](https://expressjs.com/) you can use [Route Parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) to get data from a URL. (scroll down a bit on the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the path in this format, then extract your params from req.params.

```
app.post("mediciones/sigfox_libelium/:device/:data/:time/:customData", (req, res) => {
   const {device, data, time, customData} = req.params
}
```

I'm not sure what #trama is meant to be, but I guess you can't use # in the route pattern.